# Backup SQL Server on a shared folder from Azure DevOps / Command line

Tags: sql-server, security, azure, active-directory

I need to back up my database using a command line instruction. I launch the backup instruction from a Azure DevOps Release Pipeline to back up my SQL server database on a share folder on another server. Here is my deployment group and task:

[image]

```
echo Current user: %username%
whoami
SqlCmd -S myserver1 -U myuser -P mypassword -Q "BACKUP DATABASE [mydatabase] TO DISK='\\Server7\DatabaseBackup\Backup.bak' WITH INIT"
```

Here is my log of these instructions:

```
2023-03-09T00:49:26.6349085Z ##[section]Starting: Backup Prod Database
2023-03-09T00:49:26.6973085Z ==============================================================================
2023-03-09T00:49:26.6973085Z Task         : Command line
2023-03-09T00:49:26.6973085Z Description  : Run a command line script using Bash on Linux and macOS and cmd.exe on Windows
2023-03-09T00:49:26.6973085Z Version      : 2.212.0
2023-03-09T00:49:26.6973085Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2023-03-09T00:49:26.6973085Z Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line
2023-03-09T00:49:26.6973085Z ==============================================================================
2023-03-09T00:49:27.4461085Z Generating script.
2023-03-09T00:49:27.4773085Z ========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
2023-03-09T00:49:27.4929085Z ##[command]"C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe" /D /E:ON /V:OFF /S /C "CALL "C:\azagent\A1\_work\_temp\013b8436-8475-40dd-9d49-f6166ea509cd.cmd""
2023-03-09T00:49:27.5085085Z Current user: SERVER15$
2023-03-09T00:49:27.5397085Z nt authority\system
2023-03-09T00:49:27.7269085Z Msg 3201, Level 16, State 1, Server SERVER6, Line 1
2023-03-09T00:49:27.7269085Z Cannot open backup device '\\server7\DatabaseBackup\Backup.bak'. Operating system error 5(Access is denied.).
2023-03-09T00:49:27.7269085Z Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Server SERVER6, Line 1
2023-03-09T00:49:27.7269085Z BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
2023-03-09T00:49:27.7737085Z ##[section]Finishing: Backup Prod Database
```

It seems the issue us related to the access to share folder. I go on my server7 where I created the shared folder.

Here is my sharing rules:

[image]

What is wrong? Of course I'm in a active directory domain. I can also access AD server if needed.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken here, whoami returns whatever is executing your pipeline. that is not the same thing as the service account for your SQL Server instance (which is who produces the backup file).

Comment: The machine account running SQL Server needs access/permissions to that remote server.